# Phonegap Windows 8 Splash Screen

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, splash-screen

Is there any utility in phonegap 2.5 which allows me to set up the splash screens for different windows phone devices just as in iOS and Android?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ankit.

Answer (score 1):

In config.xml, you need to have...

```
<gap:splash src="somefile.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />
```

The filename can be anything, but it has to be .jpg.

From https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml...

> Windows Phone supports a single splash image and can be defined as below. Unlike the other supported platforms, Windows Phone splash screen should be in jpg format

Microsoft actually says the filename should be `SplashScreenImage.jpg` (don't have the reference, anymore).